The HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync() method gets a broken value(getting an image from the server)
I'm trying to get a QR code generated on the server and put it in an image in the application.NET MAUI.
My HTTPGET method on server ASP.NET:
[HttpGet("{sum}")]
public async Task <ActionResult<byte[]>> Get(string sum)
{
            QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new()
            {
                DisableECI = true,
                CharacterSet = "utf-8",
                Width = 400,
                Height = 400
            };

            var writer = new ZXing.Windows.Compatibility.BarcodeWriter();
            writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            writer.Options = options;
            var QRcode = writer.Write(paymenMessage);

            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            
           
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(QRcode, typeof(byte[]));
            

        }
        else
            return BadRequest();
    }
}

I have omitted some lines of code that are not important for the question.
It is important to note that ImageConverter converts the Bitmap QRCode into an array with quotes ("), which have to be removed manually.
My method of getting an array of bytes in a mobile application:
private async void Purchase(object obj)
{
    if (sum >0 && productsInBasket is not null)
    {

        byte[] QRCode = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync($"http://10.0.2.2:5125/api/Qr/{sum}");


        string sdw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(QRCode);

        byte[] qrrWithoutQuotes  = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sdw.Replace("\"", String.Empty));

        Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"QRCode", qrrWithoutQuotes }
        };

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//QR", data);

    }
}

After that, I convert the byte array in the image using the function provided by CommunityToolkit.Maui:
<Frame HasShadow="False" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="400" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Image HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400" Source="{Binding QRCode, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToImage}}"/>
</Frame>

ViewModel:
[QueryProperty(nameof(QRCode), "QRCode")]
public class qrViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields
    private byte[] qrCode;
   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public qrViewModel()
    {
        
    }
   
    public byte[] QRCode
    {
        get { return qrCode; }
        set 
        { 
            qrCode = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

As you understood, that image was not displayed. I started to study this problem and passed a variable containing the value of a byte array to Entry and compared it with what the server provides me when requesting through the browser bar.
It turned out that when receiving data from the server, the + signs were completely deleted. This deletion happens regardless of whether I remove the quotes or not. Perhaps some other signs are being deleted.
In the image below, I presented the differences between the files

OK, I've changed the code and now I'm returning the image as a file.
return File((byte[])converter.ConvertTo(QRcode, typeof(byte[])), "image/jpeg");

After that, I get the values in the form of HttpResponseMessage, convert them to Stream and assign them to the image. There are no errors, but I still can't display the image I received.
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"http://10.0.2.2:5125/api/Qr/{sum}");
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
Image image = new Image
{
    Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream)
};

What am I doing wrong?
The solution to the image transfer problem for me was to create an ImageDTO and transfer it as a json.
Server:
 ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
 ImageDto imageDto = new ImageDto
 {
     image = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(QRcode, typeof(byte[]))
 };
 return Ok(imageDto);

Client:
ImageDto imageDto = new ImageDto();
imageDto = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ImageDto>($"http://10.0.2.2:5125/api/Qr/{sum}");


Yes, + is a reserved character in URLs (as is /); either URL-encode it (which increases the length), or use a URL-friendly base-64 variant, i.e. replace a few characters on both sides; typically + becomes - and / becomes _ - you can see this in the "Variants summary table" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table, as "base64url"

Why are you doing all of this extra work?  Why doesn’t your service just return the raw image data without all the extra conversions?

@Jason I changed the method, but unfortunately I could not achieve the desired result.

that is a very unhelpful description of the problem

Which method did you use to load the picture? Did you convert your picture to base-64 stream or load the picture by using the URL directly from the server?
